# Missing column from SELECT operation using INNER JOIN

Tags: mariadb

I'm new with SQL and DBMS.
Actually I try to SELECT some columns from two tables using inner join like this

```
SELECT  student_5701012620101.Number_id,
        subjects.Subject_id,
        student_5701012620101.Term,
        student_5701012620101.Grade, 
        student_5701012620101.Section
from    student_5701012620101 inner join subjects 
on      student_5701012620101.Subject like concat('%', subjects.Subject_id, '%');
```

and the result is

```
 Number_id        | Subject_id | Term | Grade | Section |
 +----------------+------------+------+-------+---------+
 | 010113010      |    3       | C+   |     1 |
 | 010113011      |    2       | A    |     2 |
 | 010123101      |    1       | B    |     1 |
 | 010123102      |    3       | C    |     1 |
 | 010123103      |    4       | C+   |     1 |
 | 010123104      |    5       | C    |     1 |
 | 010123105      |    3       | D+   |     1 |
 | 010123106      |    3       | C+   |     1 |
 | 010123107      |    3       | C    |     1 |
 | 010123108      |    3       | C    |     1 |
 | 010123109      |    5       | B+   |     2 |
 | 010123110      |    6       | C+   |     2 |
 | 010123111      |    6       | D+   |     1 |
 | 010123112      |    4       | C    |     1 |
 | 010123113      |    4       | D+   |     1 |
 | 010123114      |    4       | B+   |     1 |
 | 010123115      |    5       | A    |     1 |
 | 010123116      |    7       | B+   |     1 |
 | 010123117      |    5       | C+   |     1 |
 | 010123118      |    5       | A    |     1 |
 | 010123119      |    7       | C+   |     1 |
 | 010123122      |    7       | A    |     4 |
```

But when I try to select only `student_5701012620101.Number_id`
it works fine!

**Additional information**

Try to insert to new table named `regis` and `Number_id` column still missing
but when `select Number_id from regis;` 
`Number_id` are showing.

Here is the output of `select count(*), count(Number_id) from student_5701012620101 where Subject=010113010;`

```
+----------+------------------+
| count(*) | count(Number_id) |
+----------+------------------+
|        1 |                1 |
+----------+------------------+
```

and `SHOW CREATE TABLE student_5701012620101 ;`

```
| Table                 | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------
| student_5701012620101 | CREATE TABLE `student_5701012620101` (
  `Subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Credit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Section` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Grade` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Term` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Number_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

For `select len(number_id), hex(number_id). number_id from student_5701012620101 where subject = 010113010;` was an error.

Change to `select length(Number_id), hex(Number_id) from student_5701012620101 where subject = 010113010;`

```
+-------------------+------------------------------+
| length(Number_id) | hex(Number_id)               |
+-------------------+------------------------------+
|                14 | 353730313031323632303130310D |
+-------------------+------------------------------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please instead of use an image, copy & paste the command text and current result.

Comment: what happens when you do: Select Section from student_5701012620101

Comment: SELECT Section FROM student_5701012620101; worked fine, all results are correct!

Comment: By the way, missing field is Number_id field which is the first attribute. and the format like '5701012620101'

Comment: What is the output of `select count(*), count(number_id) from student_5701012620101 where subject = 010113010;`?

Comment: Also: edit the question and add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE student_5701012620101 ;` Even better for both tables.

Comment: Lets try `select len(number_id), hex(number_id). number_id from student_5701012620101 where subject = 010113010;`. My guess is you have some unprintable or control characters in those number_id values. Or there is a bug in the cli you use.

Comment: There it is! `0D` (13 in decimal) is the ascii code of the Carriage Return. You could remove those characters from the strings (with an UPDATE, using REPLACE()) and the problem will go away. A bug report to MySQL or MariaDB wouldn't hurt. It may be rejected but who knows.

Comment: you can use `select replace(number_id, '\r', '') as number_id, subject, term, grade, section from student_5701012620101;` to see if that works.

Comment: GIGO -- Get rid of the garbage (`\r`) in the data.